# Using React Context API to update a component when a new object is created

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-context

I am new to React and I am trying to use React Context API in a tutorial I am following to update a component. Initially I am loading the tweets using a json object. In the TweetForm component, on submitting the form, I am updating this tweets array by prepending a new object using the setTweets function. When I console log the tweets array it is showing me that my new tweet is being added to the array, but my tweets are not updating.

Can anyone help please? Below is the link to my code on sandbox.

[image: Edit nice-haslett-nhsj0]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `TweetForm.js`, inside `handleSubmit` function, you have to use spread operator to set new tweets like below:

```
setTweets([...newTweets]);
```

Working example : [Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/gallant-cloud-yktlo)

Comment: Hi Harish, this seems to be working in your demo link. Can you explain to me in brief why does my solution NOT work, and yours does? Thanks in advance!

Comment: The spread operator makes deep copies of data if the data is not nested. When you have nested data in an array or object the spread operator will create a deep copy of the topmost data and a shallow copy of the nested data.

Comment: In `React` and `Redux`, your app is only updated when a `change in state` is detected through `.setState()` or the `reducer`, respectively. A shallow copy could change the state before either of these are called, so when they are called, the old state would appear equal to the new state, and your elements would not be updated.

Comment: In the working example, we use `spread` operator, hence as per the above statements, React` knows the state has `changed` and calls the `render()` method again.

Comment: Since you are new in React, try understanding **React Lifecycle** first.. Hope it solves your queries, if yes you can accept the answer.